# POST json object to REST server via Postman

Tags: json, post, postman

I am getting an error while sending a json object to server. My json object is as follows:

```
{
    "AppVersion": "2.0",
    "connection": "3G",
    "received": "2015-10-30",
    "smsContent": "test string",
    "msisdn": "923453334444"  
}
```

When I send request, I am getting this error:

```
Malformed JSON: Unexpected 'c'
```

What is wrong with my json object? Can someone help here?

Comment: Your JSON seems to be valid. Show screen shots of the POSTMAN

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Postman or in the response from the server?

Comment: Could you post your local server code?

Comment: Your screenshot says, there is some error at your server code.

Comment: Yes, the error is coming from server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the incorrect syntax of your code. I also got this error and corrected by eliminating unnecessary semicolons from my code.